# Cannot get post Ajax data in Laravel Resource Controller

Tags: ajax, laravel, ajaxform

I want to submit a form without refresh the page.

Below is my jquery code for Ajax: ( the code was referring this website https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery--net-59)

```
    <script>
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $('#Calibrationform').submit(function(event) {
            var dataString = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Equipments",
                data: dataString,
                type: 'POST',
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#response_message').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                            .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        // $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });                
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('#response_message').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Failed to Submit!</h2>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        // $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });                
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    </script>
```

```
<div id="response_message"></div>
    <form id="Calibrationform" class="static p-3 col-span-8 col-start-3" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          @csrf
         <input type="hidden" name="request_type" value="Update Calibration for All Category">
         <div class="w-full rounded-lg shadow-lg p-4">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap -mx-3 mb-6 col-start-3 col-span-8 row-start-2">
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/4 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Location
      </label>
      <select id="Calibration_Filter_Location" name="Calibration_Location"
        class="form-select appearance-none block mb-3 w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">
        <option style="display: none"></option>
        @foreach ($locations as $location)
        <option value="{{$location['Location']}}">{{
          $location['Location'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      <span style="color: red">@error('Calibration_Location'){{ $message
        }}@enderror</span>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/4 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-last-name">
        Equipment's Category
      </label>
      <select id="Calibration_Filter_Category" name="Calibration_Category"
        class="form-select appearance-none block mb-3 w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500">
        <option style="display: none"></option>
        @foreach ($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category['Category']}}">{{
          $category['Category'] }}</option>
        @endforeach
      </select>
      <span style="color: red">@error('Calibration_Category'){{ $message
        }}@enderror</span>
    </div>

    <div class="w-full md:w-1/4 px-3 mb-6 md:mb-0">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2" for="grid-first-name">
        Calibration Date
      </label>
      <input
        class="appearance-none block w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-red-500 rounded py-3 px-4 mb-3 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white"
        id="grid-first-name" type="date" name="Date_of_Calibration">
      <span style="color: red">@error('Date_of_Calibration'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
    </div>
    <div class="w-full md:w-1/4 px-3">
      <label class="block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2">
        Next Due Date
      </label>
      <input
        class="appearance-none block mb-3 w-full bg-gray-200 text-gray-700 border border-gray-200 rounded py-3 px-4 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:bg-white focus:border-gray-500"
        id="grid-last-name" type="date" name="Next_Due_Date">
      <span style="color: red">@error('Next_Due_Date'){{ $message }}@enderror</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-full overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-xs">
    <div class="w-full overflow-x-auto">
      <table class="min-w-full divide-y divide-gray-200">
        <thead class="bg-gray-50">
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Equipment Name
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Registration Tag
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Status
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="px-6 py-3 text-left text-xs font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider">
              Cal Cert
            </th>
            <th scope="col" class="relative px-6 py-3">
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="Calibration_Table" class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" id="submit_btn" value="Send" />
</div>
```

The issue is I checked my network the status is 200 but my resource controller store method is not running as I use dd(request()->all()) for checking but the function is not getting executed as well.

Hope could have some hints from you, thanks in advance

After adding  return response()->json(["status"=>"success"]);
[image]

Comment: share your defined route.

Comment: I think you need to change `var dataString = $(this).serialize();` to `var dataString = $('#Calibrationform').serialize();`

Comment: Route::resource('Equipments', EquipmentController::class);    This is my route

Comment: @Espresso just tried, but still not solving the issue

Comment: You did not post your `form` elements, would you please share it

Comment: @Espresso sure, just updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can submit formdata in ajax

```
 $('#Calibrationform').submit(function(event) {
       
               var bodyFormData = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                 url: "/Equipments",
                data: bodyFormData,
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#response_message').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Submitted!</h2>")
                            .append("<p>We will be in touch soon.</p>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        // $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });                
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    $('#response_message').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                        $('#message').html("<h2>Contact Form Failed to Submit!</h2>")
                            .hide()
                            .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        // $('#message').append("<img id='checkmark' src='images/check.png' />");
                    });                
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the controller can get the data now but there is still one issue. The success: function(data) { ... } is not executing, the page get refreshed automatically and give me a blank page but I want to submit the form without refreshing the page

Comment: can you show controller store method code

Comment: public function store(Request $request)
    {
        switch ($this->request_type) {
            case 'Update Calibration for All Category':
                    ....
                }
                break;
            case 'Register Equipment':
                    ...
                ]);
                break;
            
            case 'Equipment Status Update':
                    ...  
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
    }

Comment: this is a simplified version of my store function, my complete code is a bit too long, if needed, I will update it in my post later

Comment: in store method you should return response json like return response()->json(["status"=>"success"]);

Comment: you can update to your post if its not working even after adding return response()->json(["status"=>"success"]);

Comment: @HanyiKoh Try add `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST">` in your form. The feature is called method spoofing. Hope this will help

Comment: @Hanyi Koh is any issue still ?

Comment: The page is still getting refreshed every time after ajax, I have updated my post to let you see what it show after refreshed @JohnLobo

Comment: try   event.preventDefault()

Comment: hi add   contentType: false,
            processData: false,

Comment: since form has multipart formdata so you need   contentType: false,
            processData: false,

Comment: Thanks, it has completely solved my issue!